# How I can add <br/> to f:selectItems (JSF)?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, line, break

I would like change the `f:selectItems` of a line to many lines as in the picture (`line break`).

[image]

This is my code

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{myBean.list}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.optionsList}" var="user" itemLabel="#{user.id} - #{user.name}&nbsp;#{user.lastname}" itemValue="#{user}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: That's the task of the `layout` attribute associated with [`<h:selectManyCheckbox>`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectManyCheckbox.html). It supports two types of layouts, `lineDirection` (default) and `pageDirection`. "*Orientation of the options list to be created. Valid values are "pageDirection" (list is laid out vertically), or "lineDirection" (list is laid out horizontally). **If not specified, the default value is "lineDirection".***"